# Sign when taking logarithm

Tags: logarithms

$$F=\left({\frac 1\theta}\right)^n\cdot e^{\sum_1^n x_i/\theta}$$
Taking logarithm, get
$$-n\ln\theta-\sum_1^n x_i/\theta$$
Why do we get a minus sign in the second expression before the summation?

Comment: Why *do* you have a minus sign there?  Did you read this somewhere?  If so, where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a joint density (or Likelihood) for $n$ iid Exponential random variables. If that is the case, then your first expression has a typo: there should be a minus sign before the sum in the exponent, and that's where the minus sign in the second expression comes from.